# Hosting MySites and others on the same hostname

Tags: mysite

Is it possible to use the same hostname to host everything? Since the MySites live off of another URL (e.g. "personal/"), it would seem to me that I could just pack everything into a single application and namespace. Bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is basically depend upon your infrastructure and size of the farm.
Both approaches(one web application for all or seprate web application for mysite) has pros and cons.

If you use the one web application for all, you will have one app pool that mean less consumption of farm resource and scale-ability. you have two options in this archtectur.

- Host Name Site collection
- path based site collection.
  check these resources for more information. [Link # 1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263267.aspx) [Link # 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/03/27/what-every-sharepoint-admin-needs-to-know-about-host-named-site-collections.aspx)

2nd Approach is separate Web Application for My Site host and one Web Application for other site collections. This give more control on the Mysites, improve performance and manageability. Microsoft recommend this approach.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx

At the end, i am big favour of MySite into own web application. its easy to handle, this is as per my experience.

Comment: If they exist on the same hostname does the MySite host have to run off of the root? That's where I seem to have run into trouble because we were exploring a Publishing Site at the root, and then having the My Sites live under "/personal".

Comment: i think your best bet is dedicated web application for mysite...but in other case create Host name site collection for Publishing site so it does not required root level.